# How to solve npm ERR! code ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE

Tags: node.js, npm, debian-stretch

I went to install nodejs and npm on Debian9 like this with the root account because npm is not included in the legacy debian package :

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -
    .../...
## Run `apt-get install nodejs` (as root) to install Node.js v8.x and npm

:~# 
:~# apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Now I would like to install some module with npm or to do the update of npm and I've got this error message

```
:~# npm cache clean -f
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.

:~#  npm install -g npm
npm ERR! code ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE
npm ERR! The value "4294967295" is invalid for option "family"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-03-29T11_17_37_357Z-debug.log
```

Here the link to the debug log file  : [Justpasteit](https://justpaste.it/1ixb0)

Thanks for any help

Comment: `npm install -g npm` you seem to be updating npm itself and here you don't require the flag -g

Comment: Could you read carefully. This is the command that gave me an error message  thanks

Comment: That's what I said that don't use -g

Comment: with or without the "-g" I've got the same error message

Comment: can you try to re-install node and npm and then try?

Comment: @TGW  I purged everything with `apt-get purge nodejs`  and I removed the local hidden directories like `~/.npm`. I did again the same procedure than above and I've got the some error message. In the other way I changed the procedure I found on the web and I've got this error message :  `npm ERR! Invalid argument: family must be 4 or 6` I can not install any extra package I need

Comment: hey sorry for late reply can you check the versions using npm -v and node -v

Comment: I installed Node.js v8.x as recommended for get LTS version npm version 5.6.0 and  node version v8.11.1

Comment: can you try `npm install express --loglevel info` and paste the logs here? Just make sure you use flag `loglevel info`

Comment: :~$ npm install express --loglevel info
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@5.6.0
npm info using node@v8.11.1
npm ERR! Invalid argument: family must be 4 or 6

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/system/.npm/_logs/2018-04-19T11_13_24_045Z-debug.log

Comment: sorry for the late reply, the logs seem to be same can you downgrade node version?

Comment: Try this helps https://npm.community/t/npm-install-g-typescript-fails-with-npm-err-the-value-false-is-invalid-for-option-readablehighwatermark/8668/4